# Cantor space with prefix metric

Tags: metric-spaces, cantor-set

Consider the metric space $\{$ $a_0a_1a_2....$ $:$ $a_i=0,1$ $\}$

with the metric $d(x,y)=min(I: a_i\neq b_i)$ and 0 otherwise.

Edit: I meant to say $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{2^{min(I:a_I\neq b_I)}}$ when $x\neq y$.

Show that the space is complete.

I'm not really sure how to construct a limit, perhaps there's a theorem I must consider? May I have some hints?

Comment: The definition of $d$ is confusing. If $d(a_0a_1\cdots,b_0b_\cdots)=0$ then $a_0\ne b_0$. Now how we conclude $a=b$?

Comment: @Qurultay I meant $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{2^{min(I:a_I\neq b_I)}}$ when $x\neq y$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $d(x,y) <\frac 1 N$ implies $x_i=y_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$. In any Cauchy sequence any particular coordinate, say the $k-$th coordinate becomes constant after some stage so the limit of the $k-$th coordinates exists. This gives the limit of the Cauchy sequence.

Comment: how would I approach it if $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{2^{min(I:a_I\neq b_I)}}$? when $x\neq y$?

Comment: In that case $d(x,y) <\frac 1 {2^{N}}$ implies $x_i=y_i$ for $i \leq N$. @topologicalmagician

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $2^w$. So there exists $N$ such that whenever  $m,n\geq N$, we have $d(x_n,x_m)<\frac{1}{2^K}$.
This is equivalent to saying that  $x_N|i=x_m|i$ are equal for all $i\leq K$ for all $m\geq N$. Define $x\in 2^w$ to be such that $x|i=x_N|i$ for all $i\leq K$.
So choosing $K$ to be such that $\frac{1}{2^K}<\epsilon$. whenever $n\geq N$, we have $x_n|i=x|i$ for all $i\leq K$. Thus, $d(x,x_n)\leq\frac{1}{2^K}<\epsilon$.

Note, the following lemma has been used:

Lemma 1: For $x,y \in 2^w$, $d(x,y)<\frac{1}{2^N}$ if and only if $x_i=y_i$ for all $i\leq N$.

Proof: Suppose there exists $i\leq N$ such that $x_i\neq y_i$. Put $K=min(j : x_j\neq y_j)$. Therefore, $d(x,y)=\frac{1}{2^K} \geq \frac{1}{2^i}$ $\geq$ $\frac{1}{2^N}$. Contradiction. The converse holds similarly.